# Using the same push notification channel on windows 8.1 channel

Tags: c#, node.js, push-notification, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have a windows 8.1 store app project, and in it when i user logs in i create a push notification channel like this:

```
var channelpush = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();
```

My app connects to a api in nodeJS, and after i create the PushNotificationChannel i send the `channelpush.Uri` to the api and it gets store in my user information.

then the api as a method to send push notifications with nodeJS, using [push-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/push-notify)

The problem is that, it when i connect with the same user on different devices the push channel created is different on each device.

is there a way to create a unique channel Uri depending on a user? or should i just store all channels created and send notifications too all of them (since they are all from the same user on different devices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push notification channels are deliberately per user, per app and per device.

There isn't a way to create a channel which is unique per user. You will, as you say, need to store all channels that are still valid if you have users on multiple devices.

Comment: Ok i see. How do i check if a channel is valid?

Comment: @Ric If you look at the response codes when sending messages you'll know if the channel is still valid. It's probably not in your interest to keep sending messages when the channel is no longer valid. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868245(v=win.10).aspx for more